# Can't create a new Azure Data Factory ADF with Contributor role

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-resource-group

In Azure on Subscription level I have **Azure Data Factory Contributor **Role and on the Resource Group I'm the **owner**. With this permission set I still can't create an Azure Data Factory in the Resource Group. What role/permission do I miss? It looks like after a first creation of ADF with this rol we can create it.. So what is initially needed to create ADF?

Error:
[image: error image]

add permissions on subscription level, but without any result. Can't ask for Admin rights on subscription. Looking for a minimum permission to create ADF in a Resource Group

Comment: Having contributor/owner role within the RG is sufficient to create an ADF within that RG. Do you have Privileged Identity Management enabled for your account? Then you might need to activate it

Answer (score 0):

**Azure Data Factory Contributor** Role will just allow you to create and manage child resources for ADF like dataset linked service.

**To create Azure data factory instance, you need `Owner`, `Contributor` or `administrator` role at the Azure subscription level to the user with which you are signed in.**

[image]

For better understanding refer this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-roles-permissions)

Answer (score 0):

Considering you're an owner of the RG where you're trying to create the ADF resource and looking at the error message, it's worth checking if you have the Data Factory resource provider registered in your subscription. If it isn't, you'll need to register it before being able to create an ADF instance.

[image: Data Factory Resource Provider]